# Preserving name when bulk unzipping files?

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Sorry this question is trivial, but I couldn't get it to work: I have a folder full of .zip files, each .zip file contains exactly one .xml file. The zip files have sensible names like a.zip etc., while the .xml file contained in them have some "randomname".xml

Now I want to unpack all the .zip files in the folder, preserving the name of the .zip files, so that **a**.zip gets unpacked into **a**.xml,  **b**.zip into **b**.xml etc...

I only managed to achieve a batch unpacking with the command:

`for z in *.zip; do unzip "$z"; done` 
How do I enhance this to keep the names?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have any `.xml` files in that directory when you start and each `.zip` only has exactly one `.xml` file, you could do this.

```
for z in *.zip; do
   unzip $z
   mv *.xml `echo $z | sed "s/\.zip$/.xml/"`
done
```